# How do I use re to obtain multiple variables with similar formatting?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to obtain strings with similar pattern multiple times.

For example, for my string "`SeNetworkLogonRight = *S-1-5-11,*S-1-5-32-544`", I am trying to obtain "`*S-1-5-11`" and "`*S-1-5-32-544`" and append them to a list. I tried doing the following:

```
>>> test = "SeNetworkLogonRight = *S-1-5-11,*S-1-5-32-544"
>>> print(re.findall('[*].[^.]*\d$', test))


Result obtained:
['*S-1-5-11,*S-1-5-32-544']
```

How do I obtain the values separately and append it into a list in such a format?

```
['*S-1-5-11', '*S-1-5-32-544']
```

Comment: Try `r'\*[^,]+'`

Comment: Hi Wiktor it works, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match an asterisk and any 1+ chars other than commas after:

```
r'\*[^,]+'
```

**Details**

- `\*` - an asterisk (must be escaped as it is  a special regex metacharacter otherwise)
- `[^,]+` - a negated character class matching 1 or more chars other than comma.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Vdftt8):

```
import re
test = "SeNetworkLogonRight = *S-1-5-11,*S-1-5-32-544"
print(re.findall(r'\*[^,]+', test))
# => ['*S-1-5-11', '*S-1-5-32-544']
```